Is there a fix for the varying numerical gradients calculated in the optimizer with qiskit?
I am currently trying to train a quantum circuit on Qiskit using an Azure QPU. I have some parameterized gates that I optimize using ADAMs. However, as the output of the circuit $f(x)$ is not deterministic, the numerical gradient calculated in the optimizer varies for the same input (even after performing 100 shots and calculating the expected value). Is there a fix for this, or is my interpretation of this wrong?

are you evaluating on a single output of the circuit and then updating? if so you can try the weighted average cost of the output of the circuit, weighted by how often you see said bit string.

I am evaluating on the output of the whole dataset (which is only 20 data points) and optimising using the average cost.

You may workaround this by training the circuit on parameters that can be simulated by a classical computer. You can store the quantum state at the end rather than classical outputs. Test your trained machine this way and you may still get valuable results.
